# Firebase Stripe Integration: Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError - Missing or Insufficient Permissions

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments, firebase-security

I'm integrating Stripe with Firebase for my project. I've configured all the necessary settings for the Stripe extension in Firebase, including webhook rules. However, when I initiate a checkout session in my custom code, I encounter the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Here is the code snippet from stripePayment.js:

```js
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { addDoc, collection, getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

export const getCheckoutUrl = async (app, priceId) => {
  const auth = getAuth(app)
  const userId = auth.currentUser?.uid
  if (!userId) throw new Error('User is not authenticated')

  console.log(userId)

  const db = getFirestore(app)
  const checkoutSessionRef = collection(db, 'checkout_sessions')

  const docRef = await addDoc(checkoutSessionRef, {
    price: priceId,
    success_url: 'http://localhost:5000/success',
    cancel_url: 'http://localhost:5000/cancel',
  })

  return docRef.data().url
}
And here is the relevant part from my component:

import { useStateValue } from '../../StateProvider';
import { getBasketTotal } from '../../Reducer';
import { getCheckoutUrl } from '../../stripePayment';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { app } from '../../components/firebase';

function SubTotal() {

  const handleCheckout = async () => {
    const priceId = priceIds[0]
    const checkoutUrl = await getCheckoutUrl(app, priceId)
    navigate.push(checkoutUrl);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {/* ... (existing JSX code) */}
      <div className='d-flex justify-content-center'>
        <button onClick={handleCheckout} id="checkout" className='btn-cardfav'>
          Place Order
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SubTotal;
```

Comment: The error message means that your code is trying to access a document in the database that your security rules don't grant it access to. Check which specific Firestore API call generates the error, whether that data access should indeed be allowed, and then either modify the code to match the rules or the security rules to meet your requirements.